# laravel validator not validating image image dimensions correct

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I am trying to validate the image width and height. it is giving error even if user select  image of correct resolution.

**controller code**

```
$messages = [
    'productImages.dimensions' => "Profile image must be maximum 100x100 "
];
$this->validate($request,[
    'productName'           => 'required|max:40',
    'productDescription'    => 'required|max:1000',
    'productCondition'      => 'required',
    'productImages'         =>     'required|max:5|dimensions:max_width=100,max_height=100',
    'category'              => 'required'
],$messages);
```

I want to submit that image when user select image of correct resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the fact `productImages` is plural and you have set a `max` value, I'm guessing that you are passing an array of images, not a single image.  As such, you would need to validate the dimensions for each item of the array separately.

```php
$this->validate($request,[
    'productName'           => 'required|max:40',
    'productDescription'    => 'required|max:1000',
    'productCondition'      => 'required',
    'productImages'         => 'required|max:5',
    'productImages.*'       => 'dimensions:max_width=100,max_height=100',
    'category'              => 'required'
],$messages);
```